# How to log in as Manager or employee by checking the Role column in the database?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm working on a school project using visual basic studio and mysql database. In this project there is different types of users (Manager, Employee). what I need is, when a user login to the system by his/hers username and password, the program will check from mysql database the column "Role" to identify whether this user role is (Manager or employee) if the user is the manager it will login to the manager form else it will go to the employee's form

this is part of my code:

```vb
Try
    MySqlConn.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "Select * from etdsql.employeeinfo where Username ='" & UNameTextBox.Text & "' and password = '" & PswrdTextBox.Text & "' "
    Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
    Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0

    While Reader.Read
        count = count + 1
    End While

    If count = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You are loged in successfuly")
        ETDManager.Show()
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Username and password are not correct")
    End If

    MySqlConn.Close()
Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    MySqlConn.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: If the role information is in the same table, just `Select UserRole from yourtable where username = @user and password = @hashedPassword` but we don't know your database and you haven't supplied us with anything to give a more precise answer. Also note, your sql statement is open to sql injection and should be replaced with a parameterized statement.

Comment: sorry for the lack of information :( it's my first time with VB and didn't know what to provide to you here, the Role in the same table and will try what you provide :) thanks for your help, appreciate it (^_^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
   dim role as string

   While Reader.Read
        count = count + 1
        role = Reader("Role") //This is the column's name in your db
    End While

    If count = 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("You are loged in successfuly")
        if role = "Manager" Then
             ETDManager.Show() 
        else
              ETDEmployee.Show() //This is the name of your Employee form
        end if
        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Username and password are not correct")
    End If

    ```

it could be something like that, but you will have to change the names of the column in the database and the name of the form by the names you have in your project
````

Comment: Thanks a lot (^_^) it worked perfectly, appreciate your time and work